# Disable submit button hover effect

Tags: css, button, submit

I am having a problem with a submit button on my website.  When the mouse hovers over the button, it moves slightly down (most of the time, sometimes it just glitches around the page), and the text changes colors.  I do not want the button to move at all, this is built in with a theme I added to my website, and I don't know where the source code is that is causing this.

Is there a code I can insert somewhere that will disable those hover effects of all submission buttons so that only the text changes colors, but the button does not move at all?

Comment: if your having issues with hover then you don't need to insert code rather remove code. open your .css file look for the button style and adjust or disable its hover effect

Comment: Add your relevant code to question

Comment: I cannot even find the code that is causing this which is my problem.  Do you happen to know what the code or keywords are I should be looking for?  I have spent days pouring through the file with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the button, inspect element. You should be able to look through there to find your problem. Alternatively provide a snippet of your code so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly the source code will be in CSS style sheet.
Find the "button name" in the HTML page (ie., the theme)that is annoying you and verify it in CSS. Try commenting that "button name" temporarily and see the effect.